# How ca i run a wpf application with elevated permissions?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a wpf application and i would like it to require and obtain elevated permissions. How can i do that? 
I am running .net 4.5 if with vs2013 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a manifest file for your app, e.g. `myapp.exe.manifest` and it needs to contains a section like this...

```
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <security>
    <requestedPrivileges>
      <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" />
    </requestedPrivileges>
  </security>
</trustInfo>
```

Of course, when a user runs your app it will display the usual trust dialog and ask for their consent.

Comment: To create the manifest file - right click your project, choose Add new item and in search box type 'manifest'. After the file is added - go to project properties and in Application tab select your manifest file in the dropdown